# Trying to get link using BeautifulSoup, but it's not working?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have to parse this HTML:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://link.com/'

html = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')

link = soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('https://specificlink/'))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[<a href="https://specificlink" style="display:inline-block;width:192px;"</a>]
```

I am looking specifically for the link.
After the code above I get the right link & also a `style="*************"`  after the link. How can I make it so I only get a pure link without any further HTML below it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `get()` as shown in the "extracting all the URLs section" of [Beautiful Soup Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start)

So you could adapt the `findAll` part of your code to be like the following:

```py
...
links = soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('https://specificlink/'))

for link in links:
    #you can do something else instead of printing here
    print(link.get('href'))
```